# Rename variable names with tidyverse

Tags: r

I've been struggling with a problem for a while so I was hoping to find some help here ;)

On R, I want to create a data table with two columns from a data set, modify the values of one of the two columns and calculate the number of people in the grouping for each group of variables.

I want to extract these two columns:

- REF_YEAR : a column with the years : '2000' '2001' '2002' .
- NAVLC9_COD : a column for my ship sizes : '[0-6[ m' '[10-12[ m' '[12-15[ m' ...

I want to modify NAVLC9_COD by renaming several variables from 0 to 12 meters with one variable and by renaming several variables over 12 meters with one variable.

**STEP 1.** With the idea that my script is reproducible I have created the values :

```
key_segment_size <- c("[0-6[ m","[6-10[ m","[10-12[ m")
other_size_segment <- c("[12-15[ m", "[15-18[ m", "[18-24[ m", "[24-40[ m", "[40-80[ m",">= 80 m")
```

**STEP 2.** Then I create my data table:

```
data_all_size <- data %>%
    dplyr::select(REF_YEAR,NAVLC9_COD) %>%
    str_replace(key_segment_size, "Inf. 12 m") %>% 
    str_replace(other_segment_size, "Sup. 12 m") %>% 
    droplevels() %>%
    group_by(REF_YEAR,NAVLC9_COD) %>% 
    summarize(
      number = n() 
    )
```

> Error in type(pattern) : object 'other_segment_size' not found

in the case where I replace my values by a vector, it gives :

```
data_all_size <- data %>%
    dplyr::select(REF_YEAR,NAVLC9_COD) %>%
    str_replace(c("[0-6[ m","[6-10[ m","[10-12[ m"),"Inf. 12 m") %>% 
    str_replace(c("[12-15[ m", "[15-18[ m", "[18-24[ m", "[24-40[ m", "[40-80[ m",">= 80 m"),"Sup. 12 m") %>% 
    droplevels() %>%
    group_by(REF_YEAR,NAVLC9_COD) %>% 
    summarise(
      effectif = n() 
    )
```

> Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
> Missing closing bracket on a bracket expression. (U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET, context=`[0-6[ m`)
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
> argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
> 2: In stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I also tried with the mutate and recode functions :

```
data_all_size <- data %>%
    dplyr::select(REF_YEAR,NAVLC9_COD) %>%
    mutate(Taille = recode("Inf. 12 m" = key_segment_size)) %>%
    mutate(Taille = recode("Inf. 12 m" = other_segment_size)) %>% 
    droplevels() %>%
    group_by(REF_YEAR,NAVLC9_COD) %>% 
    summarise(
      effectif = n() 
    )
```

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `Taille = recode(`Inf. 12 m `= key_segment_size)`.
> Caused by error in `recode.character()`:
> ! argument ".x" is missing, with no default

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong/what I should do instead? I'm using tidyverse, idk if that helps at all. Thank you for any help, I'm frustrated to tears.

Comment: Can you please share a few rows of `data`? `dput(data[1:10, ])` or so. Pick a suitable small subset, and restrict the columns too if there are columns in the data set irrelevant to the question.

Comment: You have created two vectors but how do you create data from those vectors? cbind? You could use "rename" in the dataframe

Comment: I *think* what you want is something like `data %>% mutate(Taille = case_when(NAVLC9_COD %in% key_segment_size ~ "Inf. 12 m", NAVLC9_COD %in% other_size_segment ~ "Sup. 12 m", TRUE ~ NA_character_))`, but it's very hard to be sure without seeing sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I finally achieve it thanks to  @Gregor Thomas comment with :

```
data_all_size <- data_sacrois %>%
 dplyr::select(REF_YEAR,NAVLC9_COD) %>%
 mutate(Taille = case_when(NAVLC9_COD %in% key_segment_size ~ "Inf. 12 m", 
                           NAVLC9_COD %in% other_size_segment ~ "Sup. 12 m", 
                           TRUE ~  "other")) %>%
 droplevels() %>%
 group_by(REF_YEAR,Taille) %>% 
 summarise(
      effectif = n() 
)
```